# How to set focus to an iOS text field?

Tags: ios, uitextfield, textfield

How do you programmatically set focus to some UITextField in iOS?

When you tap on a textfield, the keyboard pops up to begin editing the textfield.

How can you give focus to a textfield and bring up the keyboard *without* requiring the user to tap on the textfield?

Comment: for focus use [textfield becomeFirstResponder]

Comment: According to your requirement..if you want to add click event !! you can set Single TapGesture which is alternative for click event..   [YourtextField addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture]; dont forget to declare tap gesture before adding !!

Comment: It's not difficult at all to tell what's being asked here, and it's a completely legit question. Closing questions like this does not help the community.

Comment: @chaiguy The question shows no research and no previous attempt. By the new guidelines this would be still put on-hold as Offtopic

Comment: This is an absolutely valid question.  The user is not a native English writer - but so what!??!  it's an important basic question regarding iOS development - indeed the answer is "not that easy".

Answer (score 69):

Make the textField the first responder; this will also popup the keyboard:

```
[self.textField becomeFirstResponder];
```

---

And just some more typical example code which may help someone,

in your storyboard, click on one of the text fields, and set the outlets-delegate to be the class in question. In that class, in the .h file make sure that you declare that it is a UITextFieldDelegate

```
@interface Login : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>
```

Then in the .m file, you could have this for example...

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    if ( textField == self.loginEmail ) { [self.loginPassword becomeFirstResponder]; }
    if ( textField == self.loginPassword ) { [self yourLoginRoutine]; return YES; }
    return YES;
}
```

When a user clicks the "Next" button on the virtual keyboard - on the 'email' field - it will correctly move you to the password field.  When a user clicks the "Next" button on the virtual keyboard - on the 'password' field - it will correctly call your yourLoginRoutine.

(On the storyboard, on the attributes inspector, notice that you can select the text you want on the Return key ... here "Next" would work nicely on the email field and "Done" would work nicely on the password field.)

Answer (score 26):

For changing focus on the fly:

```
[yourTextField becomeFirstResponder];
```

Comment: this site is only getting input and placed to input to the another textfield. i asked how to set focus(like setOnFocus in android) in textfield and hw to create click event for textfield in iphone.

Comment: Add the TouchUpInside event for TextField

Answer (score 0):

For Swift, you can use:

theTextFieldYouWant.becomeFirstResponder()